# Get next n whole numbers for a decimal python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a decimal no

```
a = 49.5
```

I am looking to get 5+ and 5- values(whole no.s) for the given decimal no.

Final intended output is a list:

```
[45,46,47,48,49,49.5,50,51,52,53,54]
```

I'm trying to run a loop using math.ceil and math.floor but there are issues.

Is there a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: `list(np.arange(round(a)-5, round(a)+5))`?  I don't see the issue

Comment: @anon01 I tried the same, this gives [45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54], but i want actual 49.5 as the middle element

Comment: oh I see, I missed that.  If the above is `my_list`, you could do `sorted(set(my_list.append(a)))`.  Not the most elegant but should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```py
from math import ceil

a = 49.5
diff = 5
ceil_a = int(ceil(a))

output_list = list(range(ceil_a - diff, ceil_a)) + [a] + list(range(ceil_a, ceil_a + diff))

print(output_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
temp=[]
for i in range(40,55):
    if i % 5 == 0:
        j = f'{i-1}.5, {i}'
        temp.append(j)
    else:
        temp.append(i)
print(temp)
```

Comment: I try to avoid loops though

Comment: I used loops to be able to change the range.